# Sql query - getting history data with time period

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, history

I have a history table of some clients like this, etc:

```
ID    CLIENT_ID    CITY     STATUS_ID    VALID_FROM    VALID_TO
---------------------------------------------------------------
1     150          NEW YORK 1            2000-01-01    2001-01-01
2     150          NEW YORK 2            2001-01-01    2002-01-01
3     150          NEW YORK 1            2002-01-01    2003-01-01    
4     150          LONDON   1            2003-01-01    2004-01-01
5     150          LONDON   2            2004-01-01    2005-01-01
6     150          NEW YORK 2            2005-01-01    2006-01-01
...
```

I need to write a query which will return data set like this

```
CITY         VALID_FROM    VALID_TO
--------------------------------------
NEW YORK     2000-01-01    2003-01-01
LONDON       2003-01-01    2005-01-01
NEW YORK     2005-01-01    2006-01-01
```

It means that I wand to get the date period for Clint and a city by chronology. I don't care about the status.
I used query like this:

```
Select CLIENT_ID, CITY, MIN(VALID_FROM), MAX(VALID_TO)
from HISTORY_TABLE
group by CLIENT_ID, CITY
order by 3 asc
```

and it would be fine if NEW YORK does't appear again in last shown row.

Any suggestion?
I'm using MSSQL 2012

Comment: Your query is right. Probably there are dirty chars in the `City` column? Try to use the `LEN` function on it.

Comment: The problem is that that row is unique.  This is probably because there are different values.

Comment: The problem is that my query returns
New York -  2000-01-01  -  2006-01-01
London   -  2003-01-01  -  2005-01-01

which is not the same as wanted data set

Comment: What defines the correct values for "valid_from" and "valid_to" in the final result set? I'm not sure, looking at the tables you've shown, why the first row should be from 2000 to 2003, for instance. Is it because of the continuity, i.e. that there are other values that cover all the intervening time? I don't think you've explained the intended result set sufficiently for me to help with such a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH t AS
(
SELECT *, ISNULL(Lag(city,1) OVER(ORDER BY client_id,id), 'first') prevcity, 
ISNULL(Lead(city,1) OVER(ORDER BY client_id,id), 'last') nextcity FROM HISTORY_TABLE
)

SELECT t1.client_id, t1.city, t1.valid_from, ISNULL(t2.valid_to,t1.valid_to) FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2 
ON t1.city=t2.city AND t1.city=t2.prevcity AND t1.client_id=t2.client_id AND t2.city<>t2.nextcity AND t2.id>=t1.id
WHERE t1.city<>t1.prevcity
ORDER BY client_id, id
```

What this query is trying to do is

- add to the CTE table t the previous and next city, in order to be used to detect changes in the main query
- in the main query the where clause determines rows where the client starts in a new city
- the CTE t is left self joined to find the next change of city for this client
- the last record for the client will not find a next change but is covered by the isnull for valid_to

Comment: Thanks. I did some changes on your code, but you gave me the right idea.